# Debugger and Finding ROP Gadgets

Tags: linux, debugging, x86

As the title says, I am looking for a debugger that works on x86 Linux that can help find ROP gadgets, which are small pieces of assembly instructions. When I'm on Windows I use Ollydbg because it has a "Search for Sequence of Commands" utility but I have yet to find a similar debugger for Linux. Tried Evan's Debugger but it didn't have a way of searching the assembly instructions. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROP Gadget](https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/ROPgadget) has an `-asm` command line arg ("Search a specific instructions on exec segment") and supports ELF binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I know a good one from here: https://github.com/0vercl0k/rp/downloads

The linux86 version is okay, but I'd suggest downloading the `win-x64` version.
It's said to be better.
After you've downloaded it, type these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/rp
sudo mv rp-lin-x64 /opt/rp/
stat -c %a /opt/rp/rp-lin-x64
sudo chmod 755 /opt/rp/rp-lin-x64
sudo ln -s /opt/rp/rp-lin-x64 /usr/bin/rp64
```

Comment: This probably isn't what you want- it's radically simple approach but sometimes that's what you need. I find myself using objdump -D and regex text searches with egrep when the chain is relatively simple and I know the instruction set and compiler patterns well, as is the case on exploitation of RISC architectures quite often. Example case is when the goal is simply flushing a cache via SYS_nanosleep and getting a BSS, stack or heap pointer in a register into %pc. IDA pro text search with regex works better for this obviously, but it's the same thing.